# Why doesn't style-setting of the window background work?

Tags: wpf, xaml, app.xaml

Here is the App.xaml:

```
<Application>
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I also have the MainWindow.xaml. When viewed in Design mode in VS, it's background is, indeed, gray, as it should be. Anyway, when application is running, the window's background is default white.

Why?

How to fix this? I want all windows to have the standard background by default.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Following up on the answer from [CodeNaked](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142794/codenaked), you'll have to create a `Style` for every `Window` you have, but you can use the same style for all of them with `BasedOn` like this

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SomeOtherWindow}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"/>
        <!-- Add more Windows here... -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources
```

Comment: Thanks! Even   <Window.Resources><Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}" TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}"/> </Window.Resources> works.

Answer (score 21):

The problem is during runtime, the type of your window will be `MainWindow`, not `Window`. Implicit Styles are not applied to derived types of the TargetType. So your Style won't be applied.

During design time, you are designing your `MainWindow`, but I suspect it creates a `Window` as the basis.

You'd need to change the type to match your window's type.

Comment: Thank you! The fact that it works in the design view is confusing.